# How to automatically stage files in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, staging

Every time I want to commit changes I've made, I have to check the box "Unstaged files" even though I'd previously committed them, and have only modified their contents.

I can't find a setting for this anywhere. Is there one? If not, is there a reason? And/or is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're facing is called a [two stage commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878358).  This is actually tremendously useful:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69178/what-is-the-benefit-of-gits-two-stage-commit-process-staging
>
> 1. Split work into separate commits.
>
> You've probably many times opened a
>   file to write a single-line fix, but at the same time you spotted that
>   the formatting was wrong, some documentation could be improved, or
>   some other unrelated fix. With other RCSes you'd have to write that
>   down or commit it to memory, finish the fix you came for, commit that,
>   and then return to fix the other stuff (or create a ball-of-mud commit
>   with unrelated stuff). With Git you just fix all of it at once, and
>   stage+commit the single line separately, with git add -i or git-gui.
>
> 2. Don't break the build.
>
> You're working on a complicated modification.
>   So you try different things, some of which work better than others,
>   some which break things. With Git you'd stage things when the
>   modification made things better, and checkout (or tweak some more)
>   when the modification didn't work. You won't have to rely on the
>   editor's undo functionality, you can checkout the entire repo instead
>   of just file-by-file, and any file-level mistakes (such as removing a
>   file that has not been committed or saving+closing after a bad
>   modification) does not lead to lots of work lost.

See also:

- http://betterexplained.com/articles/aha-moments-when-learning-git/
- http://gitolite.com/uses-of-index.html

Comment: "useful" is in the eye of the beholder. IMO it would be far more useful to have everything start out staged. I could then unstage if I wanted. YMMV, which is why this sort of thing should be settable.

Comment: You didn't answer the primary question of whether or not this setting is available.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is "No. You can't do that."

The reason is that the designers believe a two-stage commit would be useful. While that is true, there is still no reason why they couldn't have a two-stage commit where everything starts out staged unless you unstage it. Looking in from the outside, this looks like a case where the designers believe they understand what is right for a user better than the user does.